# User to download file to their local directory

Tags: html, python-3.x, download, bottle

Backend - I wrote a python script that creates a csv file after some aggregation.

Frontend - Once the method finished running and the .csv file is generated and saved to a directory in the server, I want to be able to prompt the user to save the .csv file on their local computer (just like the windows prompt you get when you press "save as..." on a webpage).

This is an example of what I've done so far from what I learned in [Return Excel file in Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449325/return-excel-file-in-flask-app) and [Download a file when button is pressed on web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53160441/download-a-file-when-button-is-pressed-on-web-application) :

Sample code:

```
with open(save_path + unique_filename + ".csv", 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerow(['name', 'place', 'location'])
```

HTML:

```
@app.route('/login', method='POST')
def do_login():
    category   = request.forms.get('category')
    return '''
    <html><body>
    Hello. <a href="/getCSV"> Save Results </a>
    </body></html>
    '''

@app.route("/getCSV", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def getPlotCSV():
    return send_from_directory(save_path + unique_filename + ".csv", as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   run(app, host = 'localhost', port = 8000)
```

My questions are:

1) send_from_directory is from flask, what is the bottle equivalent?

2) Where in the code do I place the csv I created so the user can download it to their local machine?

3) What else is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottle example:  From https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html

```
@route('/download/<filename:path>')
def download(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/static/files', download=filename)
```